# Aliasing in \texttt and \textsf

Tags: fonts, aliasing

I am interested in using Charter BT font from [tug.org](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/charterbt/). Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    ABCD\\
    \texttt{ABCD}\\
    \textsf{ABCD}
\end{document}
```

It worked just fine until I noticed that `\texttt` and `\textsf` were experiencing some kind of aliasing.

[image]

Is this one of the font's "features?" Is there something we can do to fix it?

Comment: I have tried various viewers: TexStudio, TeXworks, Adobe, SumatraPDF, Firefox, Chrome. Pretty much everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mathdesign` package changes the default serif font, but not the default typewriter and sans-serif font. Due to T1 encoding, these come from the EC fonts. And if one does not install the (rather large) `cm-super` fonts, these fonts are indeed bitmap fonts that some viewers might display like this. A simple solution would be to use the LM fonts for typewriter and sans-serif by loading `lmodern.sty` in the beginning:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    ABCD\\
    \texttt{ABCD}\\
    \textsf{ABCD}
\end{document}
```